# Geometric equation for summation of 3 to power of x?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking for a formulas for this expression.

$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} 3^i$

Does anyone know if there is a formulas for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} 3^i = {3^m - 1}/2$

this is due to 
$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} 3^i = 1 + 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^{m-1}$

$= (3-1)\times(1 + 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^{m-1})/(3-1)$

$= (3^m-1)/(3-1)$

$= (3^m-1)/(2)$

Answer (score 0):

The title suggests you've heard the term "geometric series" ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)). As explained in the link,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}r^i=\frac{r^m-1}{r-1}$$
for any $r\neq 1$. Thus, in your case,
$$\sum_{i=0}^m3^i=\frac{3^{m+1}-1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Formula is $$=\frac{3.(3^{m}-1)}{2}$$

This is a geomteric series, whose formula is given by

$$\frac{a.(r^{n}-1)}{r-1}$$

$a$ is the first term, 
$r$ is common ratio, $n$ is number of terms

here $a=r=3$, 
$n =m$

Comment: The first term here is $3^0=1$.